# Quadratic Variation and Covariation of Poisson Processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I need to campute the quadratic variation for a compound poisson process defined as $X_{t}=\sum_{i=1}^{N_{t}}{Y_{i}}$. I also know that the compensated poisson process can be expressed as $X_{t}-\lambda t E[Y]$ and that the quadratic variation is: $[X,X]_{t}=|x_{t}|^{2}-2\int_{0}^{T}{X_{u^{-}}dX_{u}}$.

My idea to show this, was to substitute inside the quadratic variation and I find:

$$ \begin{align} [X,X]_{t}&=|\sum_{i=1}^{N_{t}}{Y_{i}}|^{2}-2\int_{0}^{T}{X_{u^{-}}d(X_{u}-\lambda E[Y]u)}\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{N_{t}}|{Y_{i}}|^{2}-2\left[\int_{0}^{T}{X_{u^{-}}d(X_{u})}-\lambda E[Y]\int_{0}^{t}{X_{u^{-}}du}\right]
\end{align}$$
Now, can I say that $\int_{0}^{T}{X_{u^{-}}d(X_{u})}=\lambda E[Y]$? and that $\int_{0}^{t}{X_{u^{-}}du}=1$?

To compute the Quadratic covariation should I use the polarization identity?

Comment: 1. What happened to the mixed terms when squaring the sum? 2. No, these equations do not hold true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "square bracket" of $X$ is just
$$
[X,X]_t=\sum_{s\le t}(\Delta X_s)^2=\sum_{i=1}^{N_t}Y_i^2,
$$
and the associated "angle bracket" (predictable quadratic variation) is the compensator of $[X,X]$, namely
$$
\langle X,X \rangle_t = \lambda t E[Y^2_1].
$$